# ImageView to display image from Windows network share

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I'm trying to display an image from a Windows network share.  I've downloaded Picasso and installed that.

Currently I have a button that upon clicking it, opens a new activity.  My onCreate() method is as follows...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);


    try{
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(this).load("file://server/dir1/dir2/test.png").into(view);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

If I change the above to view an image on our webserver, it works just fine...which the code can be seen below...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);


    try{
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://domain.com/test.png").into(view);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

I need to view a plethora of images on a network share...Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a better way around this...I added the network share as a virtual directory on my web server, so now I can use an http URL to retrieve the pictures, and everything works as I want it to.